# How to pass a login success from controller/backend to viewer/GUI utilizing Tkinter?

Tags: python, mongodb, authentication, tkinter

I have a gui program with two classes - controller.py and viewer.py. I don't need a model as I'm using pandas Dataframes.

Viewer is the GUI. This is where all the shiny buttons are.
Controller is where all the functionality is.

I need to be able to login to a database and then destroy the login window. Or fail to login and keep it until a success.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from controller import deleteField, deleteDups, clean, importFromExcel, ant, scrubAddresses, login
import constant

root= tk.Tk()
top = Toplevel()

top.title("Login")
entryu = Entry(top) #Username entry
entryp = Entry(top) #Password entry
loginButton = Button(top, text="Login", command=lambda: login(entryu.get(), entryp.get())) #Login button
cancelButton = Button(top, text="Cancel", command=lambda: cancel()) #Cancel button
```

login is in a different class - controller.py.

```
def login(user, password):
    try:
        client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://' + user + ':' + password + 'junkyoudontneedtoknow')
        db = client['My Database']
        return True
    except Exception as inst:
        print(type(inst))    # the exception instance
        print(inst.args)     # arguments stored in .args
        print(inst)          # __str__ allows args to be printed directly,
                             # but may be overridden in exception subclasses
        print("Login Failed, try again. \n")
```

So the func returns True on successful login, and nada on unsuccessful.

But this is where it's called:

```
loginButton = Button(top, text="Login", command=lambda: login(entryu.get(), entryp.get()))
```

So... how would tkinter ever know when True gets returned so it can deiconify root and destroy top? I need to do that 'client, db = client[]' thing in controller so it can do all of its work. So shrugging and moving it back to viewer isn't the greatest idea ever.

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a callback function to the logging function. I will give you an example. In the `test.py` file I used the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from test2 import function

root = tk.Tk()

def callback(boolean):
    if boolean:
        root.destroy()

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var2 = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable = var1).pack()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable = var2).pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=lambda: function(var1.get(), var2.get(), callback)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In this example, my button call a function that is defined in other file (`test2.py`) and pass to this function the values of the two enters, stored in the variables `var1` and `var2`. The callback function will close the window if receiving `True` (actually, not None).

In the test2.py I defined the `function` as following:

```
def function(var1, var2, callback):
    callback(int(var1) > int(var2))
```

So it will call the callback function defined in the interface file (`test.py`) with an argument that will be True if the value of `var1` is greater than `var2`.

In your case, the login function will call the callback function with True or False depending if login is successful or not.

As an extra tip, I suggest you to use the Entry password widget with the argument `show='*'`. This way you cant see what is being typed in the password.